# Where can I run application verifier commands

Tags: c++, visual-studio, runtime-error, application-verifier

I am using application verifier for runtime debugging. Sometimes, when it reports a problem, there is a mention of a command to run.

> VERIFIER STOP 0000000000000210: pid 0x2738: Critical section not
>   initialized.
>
> ```
>    0000000006F14C40 : Critical section address. Run !cs -s <address> to
>    get more information.
> ```

In which console am I supposed to run `!cs -s <address>`? I am developing under [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio)

Comment: Before going too deep with windbg you can try to set a breakpoint at the line where the problem occurred or earlier in the stack. Run again the application and see if you can figure out what is the problematic variable. Probably you will need to run the application multiple time and use F11 a lot but sooner o later the problematic line will be discovered. Most of the times is easier and faster to troubleshot the problem in this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Application Verifier works best with windbg. !cs is a windbg extension that gives you information about critical sections. Other checks, such as the pageheap functionality of Application Verifier will use other windbg extensions to provide you with additional information.

One place you can find windbg is in the Windows SDK.